# TCA type input eval user functions don't work properly in IRRE mode

Tags: eval, inline, typo3

I have a problem with the custom eval functions when the record is called from an IRRE field, in particular with the JavaScript function.

For example I open to edit the base record of "table1", then I click an IRRE field to create a record to the "table2", the fields of the records of "table2" have eval user functions that works Ok in normal editing, but when in IRRE the functions only work after save the form, so the first time when the record is created those functions are not doing them jobs.

I don't understand where is the problem, maybe the Javascript code is not loaded. How can I add that file manually to the backend template? How can I face this situation?

I tried to debug with console and when the functions are called these files are present:

alt_doc.php:765

jsfunc.evalfield-e6a70fd19bf472ef08fa4754aae256b8.js:69

jsfunc.tbe_editor-def45aac90022eed51193264931eefb3.js:660

alt_doc.php:408

alt_doc.php:409

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a problem with the launch of the JS code. When you open the parent form the JS code of the fields that use eval in the IRRE form is not launched, when you saved the form with the IRRE created, Typo3 reloads the frame and now the JS is accesible.

I don't know a trasparent way to by-pass this, you must save the parent form after create the IRRE form in order to use the JS custom eval code of the IRRE form.